# discord.py TypeError: find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.9

I am programming a bot in python 3.9 using the discord.py library and I am currently trying to fetch a role with the name "Knight". The line of code that gets the role is raising a type error: `discord.py TypeError: find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`. The code causing this being `knightRole = discord.utils.find(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Knight")`. The following code creates the role if it does not exist (if `knightRole` returns `None`).

Here is my code followed by the traceback:
[image: Code]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `discord.utils.find` function takes a predicate function (so a function or lambda that returns `True` or `False`) and a sequence, like so:

```
knightRole = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Knight', ctx.guild.roles)
```

You could also use the similar `discord.utils.get`, which does have the interface you apparently expected here:

```
knightRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Knight')
```

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.find)

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly. I knew I should have read `discord.utils.find` when it said that `discord.utils.get` was "an alternative for find()"...